# How can an EM wave create fields in a vacuum?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, vacuum

I know there are a number of questions asking how EM waves can travel through a vacuum.  My question is specifically about the oscillating electric and magnetic fields.  To my understanding, magnetic fields are thought to be created by the net spin of electrons.  If we are in a vacuum, there are presumably no electrons, so how can a magnetic field be produced?

I understand that magnetic fields are produced by electric fields and vice versa but how can they physically exist without any particles (electrons).

Comment: Please check out Maxwell's equation. A change in an electric field generates a B-field.

Comment: *How can an EM wave create fields in a vacuum?* EM waves *are* just oscillations in the EM field.

Comment: *Magnetic fields are thought to be created by the net spin of electrons.* Yes, but magnetic fields would exist even if no particles had spin. Any moving charge creates a magnetic field, as does a changing electric field.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I understand that changing electric fields create B-fields.  G. Smith, if I am understanding you correctly, EM waves are just disturbances (oscillations) in the already existing magnetic field, not actually a magnetic field of their own?  If so, that helps a lot.  The more I think about it the obvious it is.  Thank you very much

Comment: EM waves are derived when you take the wave equation and use Maxwell's equations to solve it. EM waves propagate through the EM field which is not really a physical thing, more a property of space.

Comment: EM waves are just disturbances/oscillations in the already existing electromagnetic field (which might have a negligible strength in some places except when the wave passes through). We sometimes talk about the field of object A, or the field of object B, but in reality there is only one EM field, extending throughout the universe.

Comment: After EM waves have been generated by currents or flipping spins, they travel away from their sources.

Answer (score 1):

according to Maxwell's equations, the time derivative of the electric field is equivalent to a rotation of the magnetic field, which makes a pair of electric and magnetic fields self-propagating through a vacuum.

So, for example, the rapid movement of charges back and forth along a wire in a vacuum will create a rapidly-varying magnetic field in the vicinity of the wire, which will create a rapidly-varying electric field in the vicinity of the wire, etc., etc. and an electromagnetic *wave* then propagates away from the wire through the vacuum- even though there are no electrical charges or little chunks of magnetic material distributed throughout the vacuum.

In this example, the wire is an *antenna* and the wave is a *radio wave*.

Comment: This is not strictly correct: "a time-varying electric field creates a time-varying magnetic field". Rather the time derivative of one is _the same thing_ as the rotation of the other.

Comment: will correct.    -nn

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is photons, which create an electromagnetic field, no matter if vacuum or not. In a vacuum, the speed of photons is c=299792458 m/s and is also related to electromagnetic wave/ light shape.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. Unfortunately, I believe that you are not answering the question. The question is about a classical description of light, and you discuss a quantum description.

Answer (score -1):

You are asking how there can be fields in vacuum, even though as you say there are no electrons present to create the EM field itself.

You are confused because of the definition of vacuum. Even though vacuum in some context might mean sometimes the same as empty space, the fields still fill the fabric of spacetime throughout, that is, for example the EM field exist in all of spacetime everywhere.

> Quantum field theory implies that the vacuum is full of virtual particles that emerge and quickly disappear. Those virtual particles make their impact on other objects - for example, they make the electromagnetism a little bit weaker at long distances (and stronger at very short distances) than what one expects from the classical Coulomb's law etc.
>   However, quantum mechanics implies that the vacuum corresponds to a very particular "state" - a vector on the Hilbert space - called |0⟩. It is completely unique and as empty as you can get. In particular, it is the eigenstate of the energy operator with the minimum allowed energy - essentially zero. (More precisely, the vacuum energy density is nothing else than the magnitude of dark energy but this energy only becomes sizable for huge, cosmological volumes of space.)
>   The uncertainty principle of quantum mechanics implies that when one measures things such as the intensity of the electric field in the vacuum - i.e. when the physical system is found in the state |0⟩ - one may get many random values. It is not allowed for the electric and magnetic fields to be exactly zero, much like a particle can't have a well-defined position and velocity in the quantum mechanics of one particle.
>   So even though the vacuum has a well-defined (minimal) energy and it is as low as we can get, so the vacuum is as empty as we can get, and there are no particular "atoms" or other particles sitting in the vacuum, there's a lot of activity going on in the vacuum which can be seen by the fact that the measurements of various things, such as the density of energy at a given point, will lead to random results that are not strictly zero.

[Does vacuum (empty space) exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/does-vacuum-empty-space-exist/6467#6467)

Electrons are excitation of the electron field. When an electron/atom emits a photon (EM wave), that EM wave travels as you say throughout vacuum. The photons (that build up the EM wave) themselves are excitation of the EM field that fills spacetime throughout. These fields exist everywhere even when there is no EM wave traveling. When there is an EM wave traveling, this means that the excitation of the EM field (photons) is propagating throughout spacetime.

So the answer to your question is, that even though in vacuum there might be no electrons (excitation of the electron field) present, the fields themselves are present everywhere throughout space. The excitation of the EM field (photons) can and do propagate independently of the source (electron, the excitation of the electron field), and these fields exist everywhere even in vacuum throughout space.