# Time reversed laser

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, laser

Recently, I read an article on time reversed laser. I don't know why they call it a time reversed. I have a doubt that why they use two laser in the device. And what is an anti-laser?
The device absorbs the particular frequency of light which means some energy is lost. What happens to the lost energy?

Comment: Compare and contrast: [Anti-laser: How sure we are that energy is transported?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5743/520), [Recently publicized experiment on destructive interference between two laser beams](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9628/520) and [Is the time reversed laser really a laser?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43672/520) (and [the OP's answer to the last of those](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/60006/520)). On the whole I suspect we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @dmckee: I think we can't close the question as a duplicate of the *third* one ;-)