# Is it possible to make a destructive interference generator?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, interference, superposition

Is it possible to make a light source that shifts waves of light to cause destructive interference to cancel the other light source out to make it fully dark?

Comment: Polarizer sheets work using the mechanism you've described.

Comment: @YashasSamaga So if I shine light through a polarizer sheet onto where another light (which is not being polarized) shines, would the polarized light cancel out the other light?

Comment: And where the energy of the light from the sources will go? For light destructive interference without constructive interference isn't possible.

Comment: This refers to a part of the question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88422/fully-destructive-interference/88437#88437  and  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9628/recently-publicized-experiment-on-destructive-interference-between-two-laser-bea . Although - I have seen only a **vague claim**, that 'because of energy conservation' there will be always some part the will be interfering constructively

Answer (score -1):

in theory yes you can do it.  But real word is harsh, the light you see every day is mix of almost all wave lenght so to interfire whit that you would need emiter that send all waves but moved by pi/2 (to make it simple i asume every wave is sinusoidal). It might work at still viev but at dinamic you wolud have to know the future to destroy incomig light. Beside that it will work as long as you stay behind you foton destroyer (sorry for broken eng)