# Noise cancellation solution for pool filter motor

Tags: noise

I live in a condo, there is pool filtering equipment located outside my bedroom. Can anyone suggest a noise cancellation solution for the hummmm of the motor?. The equipment is in a 12ft x 12ft x 3ft space and fully enclosed but not air tight. [image: filtering system]

Thanks for your help.
Jack

Comment: Must be a big pool to require 3 [DE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatomaceous_earth) filters and (at least) 2 chlorine tanks (bottom left tubs). That aside, this probably isn't the best place to ask such a question.

Comment: It's probably better to try to absorb as much of the noise as possible rather than try to cancel it.  Lots of companies sell acoustic absorbing foam.  Another thing to try is isolating the source of the vibration (if possible) with a viscoelastic material like a viscoelastic pad.  I use viscoelastic pads to isolate my vibratory rock tumblers and it works great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outdoor Active Noise Canceling Speaker](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87833/outdoor-active-noise-canceling-speaker).

Answer (score 1):

I see from your picture that most of the surrounding of the pool is made of straight and rigid objects, these objects make more reflections of sounds than absorptions, also allow for easy transmission.

You can do a little soundproofing of the system, you can fill it with soft stuff like old rugs or cushions. You can also line the trap door with egg cartons(these are widely used in diy home soundproofing) I would not suggest you to do a high grade soundproofing as that stuff requires sealing off openings, and you do not want to seal anything from your equipment. Just light soundproofing should reduce the sound considerably.

Answer (score 0):

This may be more expensive, but here's an estimate:  the pool equipment is most likely running on 60Hz power, which typically leads to 120Hz noise.  In air, that's a wavelength of roughly three meters.  What *that* means is that you could build/buy an adaptive noise cancellation system for your apartment, as it'll be reasonably good at phase-matching the external sound over a wide area from a single loudspeaker.