# Interference and energy question here

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, interference

So Im reading this material on interference and I noted the following sentence :

> During the interference of the light of two coherent light sources,the
>   intensity of the radiation changes periodically from one point to
>   another,alternating the maximums and the minimums of the interference.

This made me question .What is going to happen to the energy transmitted by the sources before and after the interference?

Comment: Related post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23930/what-happens-to-the-energy-when-waves-perfectly-cancel-each-other

Answer (score 4):

The energy is conserved but it becomes "lumpy"- more in some places (directions), less in others. Total over all directions is the same.