# When two waves undergo complete destructive interference then what happens to the energy of the two waves?

Tags: waves, energy-conservation, interference, superposition

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23953
Here the author of the answer mentions that complete destructive interference acts as a mirror .

As the potential energy of the waves is zero they only have kinetic energy given that the waves were mechanical and transverse .

As per my understanding the wave will move back and forth having only kinetic energy and zero potential energy.
How is this possible?
 How can I imagine any motion as the wave was initially transverse? 
How does that kinetic energy travel back and forth?
Assume that they waves are continuously cancelling each other out.

For example two people are holding a rope from opposite sides and they are producing waves in the rope so that they cancel each other out continuously. 
So the potential energy of the rope is zero at all instants

Comment: I think you need to proofread your question.

Comment: Thanks , I hope it is clear now

Comment: I was mostly talking about the body. And you do realize that destructive interference does not mean the waves suddenly disappear altogether, right?

Answer (score 2):

> As the potential energy of the waves is zero they only have kinetic energy given that the waves were mechanical and transverse .

A transverse mechanical wave will in general have both KE and PE. This sentence is true only at the instant when the waves are canceling.

> As per my understanding the wave will move back and forth having only kinetic energy and zero potential energy.

There is nonzero PE at all other times.

Answer (score -2):

Your example is a good choice but is misinterpreted.  Two waves (of equal amplitude and wavelength) going in opposite directions on  a rope produce a standing wave, canceling  each other only at the nodes (every half wavelength).  The energy missing from the nodes appears at the anti-nodes where the amplitude is doubled.  (This requires only a person shaking one end and a fixed (or free) opposite end where reflection occurs.)  If the pattern is stable, the input force supplyies only enough energy to overcome friction.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. The OP is just asking about waves that interfere destructively, which can happen in open space.

Comment: What's not right?  I was referring to his example and my answer was based on decades of demonstrating transverse standing waves on a long narrow stretched spring.  By the way, can you think of any situation where two waves fron different sources cancel each other in all points in a given region?